# How to get mp3 tags without downloading it

Tags: python, mp3, mutagen

I have this code :

```
rangeheader = {'Range':'bytes=-128'}
req = urllib2.Request('http://xyz.mp3',headers=rangeheader)
res = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print res.read()
```

Now when i'm writing these tags in a new mp3 file and then using mutagen on that it is showing

```
audio = MP3("test.mp3")
print audio.info
```

Errors :-

```
raise HeaderNotFoundError("can't sync to an MPEG frame")
mutagen.mp3.HeaderNotFoundError: can't sync to an MPEG frame
```

How to fix it.

Comment: How are you writing these MP3 tags to a new mp3 file? Using python?

Comment: I'm not writing tags.. just fetching it from an external source.
i.e., from other's server (remotly).

Comment: Your question and the response seem to be a bit ambiguous. What I meant to ask was how are you creating **test.mp3**?

Comment: `fh = open(test.mp3, "w")`
`fh.write(res.read())`
`fh.close()`


like this !

I don't know how to provide headers (Here MPEG i think so)